# Datatable reset to initial sort order

Tags: .net, sorting, datatable

is there a way to remove the sort order from a datatable? I know about the function Datatable.Select to sort using a specific column (or a combination of columns) but I would like to remove the sorting completetly.

To explain a little bit more: I get an unknown number of unsorted data rows in a string, which I like to show in a datagrid control.

Due to performance reasons the data is transfered into a datatable (call it "init_data") and this datatable is bound to the datagrid (WPF right now but this is not important for the problem).

During sorting in my datatgrid, I have to sort the "init_data" using the Select function.
As this might be thousands of rows, I cannot keep the original "init_data" but have to transfer the sorted data to a new datatable (call it "sort_data")

But once the datatable is sorted, I cannot display the original sort order again.

Any ideas?
Regards
Klaus

Comment: Have you tried to use a DataView instead of an array of DataRows?

Comment: Create a column just to support the sort and number 1 - x.  Then you just sort on the column to get the original back.

Comment: Blam, I think this is the only way to go - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a column just to support the sort and number 1 - x.
Then you just sort on the column to get the original back.